# Installing or building vim with +python3 support for Python 3.7.x on linux

Tags: macos, vimscript-python

I've got Vim installed on MacOS using Brew and it installs with `+python3` support for Python 3.7.2 by default.

I'm writing a Vim plugin which utilises some Python 3.7 and would like this to be able to work on parity with Linux with how it works on MacOS.

In a Docker container with Ubuntu Bionic I've tried installing Python 3.7.2 and Vim; and it installs Python 3.6 and links to this version.

I've tried installing Vim from source in the container and it will build for 3.6 but not for 3.7.

On Linux, running the following to configure the build:

```
./configure --with-features=huge --enable-cscope --enable-multibyte \
  --enable-rubyinterp --enable-pythoninterp --enable-python3interp \
  --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu \
  --enable-fail-if-missing
```

fails with the message:

> checking if compile and link flags for Python 3 are sane... no

I've thought of downgrading the MacOS Vim version to 3.6 and coding the plugin to that version but thought I would explore options to get it working on Linux with Python 3.7 first.

Also, if this is not the appropriate forum for this question, please let me know and I will move it to a stack-exchange site more appropriate.

Comment: Have you checked the faq https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-35.10?

Comment: Thanks for that - I have now, still doesn't help - it's in a docker container and vim isn't preloaded.

Comment: and `apt-get build-dep vim-gtk` does not help?

Comment: thanks, but that's for the x11 dependencies - without installing anything else and running for build-dep it didn't even include +python letalone +python3

Comment: ... i think i need to learn how to read makefiles

Comment: No, the vim-gtk contains python3 bindings, so `apt-get build-dep vim-gtk` should install the necessary packages needed to build and link a vim with python3 support.

Comment: I believe you need to install either `python3-dev` on Debian or `python3-devel` on Centos.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably your default `python3` is `3.6`. You need, then, tell the build process to use `python3.7`. You can do that with the parameters `--with-python3-command`:

```
./configure --with-python3-command=python3.7 \
            --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu \
            ... (other config params) ...
```

HTH

Comment: this looks promising but I'm getting: `configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-python3-command` running that command.

Comment: i am going to try a variation of this when I have some time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30449124/512965

Comment: Strange... It worked for me. Stupid question: did you passed also the parameter `--enable-python3interp=yes` ?

Comment: Not a stupid question. No i didn't. I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: looks like it doesn't work with --enable-python3interp=yes either, sorry. do you have a dockerfile of it working?

Comment: I've managed to create a Docker image to test it. You can find it here: https://github.com/jalexandretoledo/DockerUbuntuPython37

Comment: NOTE: that a good chance config dir in `/usr/lib64/python3.x`

Answer (score 12):

`make clean distclean`
before running the `configure` command for vim. This worked for me. There was lots of cached items hanging around from before that were interfering with vim `configure`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Have you been able to try this with the OPs case? This answer could benefit from more detail specific to the question

Comment: This worked for me, it looks like after trying several commands around the repo is dirty, this will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message

> checking if compile and link flags for Python 3 are sane... no

and was running essentially the same command. The issue was with the line:

```
--with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu
```

which was incorrect.

I checked the actual location of the config using the output of:

```
python3.7-config
```

and that fixed the issue.